# Upper pulley too far from cassette

Tags: derailleur-rear, 1x11

I'm doing a 1x conversion with a Shimano SLX (M7000) groupset on an old road frame.

I just installed the rear derailleur and the pulley is too far away from the cassette. 18mm from the max cog (recommended is 4mm-5mm). However the B screw is all the way out and screwing it in only widens the gap. Not sure what's going in. Maybe the chain is too short?

Some photos of the setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Wpp.jpg

- RD-M7000 GS Rear Derailleur Medium Cage
- CS-M7000 Cassette: - 11 Speed 11-42T

Comment: Could you upload a picture of the whole drive-train from the right side as well?

Comment: Observation: neat older steel frame with horizontal drop outs. The hub axle is all the way up in the drop outs and that could be placing it higher than normal?

Comment: It looks to me like the chain is 2-4 links too short.

Comment: @Carel I added a photo of the drive-train

Comment: @Swifty interesting observation, do you recommend putting spacers there or just eyeballing it?

Comment: @DanielRHicks what method do you recommend for sizing the chain? I did a big-big plus two.

Comment: Big- big plus two works best.  Remember that if youre adding a quick link, that counts as 1 so that brings the cut point on the wrap sizing to +1 where you end with inner links on each side of the chain after the cut.

Comment: Is this a functional issue, or does it just upset the look ?  I see a lot of tooth-chain engagement on the big cog - is it that far away from the little cogs (big/hard gears) ?

Comment: @swifty I think you found at least half the cause right there -  Totally make that an answer.   We notice the bare metal part where the old axle was, and now the "claw adapter" is not there, the axle can go all the way back which is higher up.   Solutions: lower the axle in the dropouts for a test.  If that helps, have to create a "filler" for the drive side, perhaps by modifying an old-school hanger.

Comment: To me the chain looks too long. When it is on the large cog, the derailleur cage should be almost horizontal. It is certainly very slack when on the smallest..

Comment: Thanks everyone. Lowering the axle in the dropouts has essentially fixed everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, take the chain off and shift the derailleur into position and see what happens. If it's still too far away, you can possibly eliminate the short chain (which does look too short) from the equation.

Without the chain, you should be able to see what is causing the derailleur to sit at that position.

You should be able to find what's preventing the jockey wheel from coming in closer contact with cassette ring by flexing and contracting all the movable parts on the derailleur.

Possibly, the derailleur hanger places it too far out?

Comment: Super helpful. Moving the wheel so that the hub is lower in the drops has essentially fixed everything. And shifting is *much* better. I believe a longer chain would have the same effect without moving the wheel but haven't tried. Thanks!

Comment: Getting closer... I don't like the QR not being nestled full in the drops (unless they are horizontal drops with an adjuster screw) but looking at the wear on that bike, it seems that's been how it was run... you might get away with it with the 45degree angle drops, but getting things lined up just right will be tricky... I'd keep sleuthing.